# How to integrate with jsonwebservices in Android?

Tags: java, android, json

I'm implementing json_web services in my Android application. I want to send the json data on jsonwebservices which is created in Java. When I run the application data does not send from the Android and does not show any error and also does not show any type of exception.

How can I identify whether my data is sent or not?

Here is my Activity Code:

```
 public class Login extends Activity
{
    Button btnLogin;

    EditText etextUsername , etextPassword;
    String strUserName , strPassWord ; 
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONObject jObject ;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref1;
    String str_Device_IP_Address=null;
    JSONArray user = null;
    String pref_filename = "IP_ADDRESS";

    static final String KEY_REQUEST_ID = "RequestId";
    static final String KEY_REQUEST_CODE = "RequestCode";
    static final String KEY_CHANNEL_ID = "ChannelId";
    static final String KEY_IP_ADDRESS="IPAddress";
    static final String KEY_USERNAME="UserId";
    static final String KEY_PASSWORD="Password";

    static final String KEY_REQUEST="Request";
    static final String KEY_VENDOR_ID="VendorId";


        String RequestId="77777";
        String RequestCode="001";
        String stringChannelId="MobileApp";
        String strIpAddress = null;

         private String textToEncrypt = "Hi, this is a test to check its gone work or not.";
        String encrypted = "MzA3RDBCMjMxMjQzNzcxREUxMUYxNjg1NzgwOTU1MjU1M0FDOUZEN0M3Q0JGQ0Q5MTI2NEIyNTE2"
                   + "OTQwQTc3NjM2QTBCRDFDMUEyNkUwRjlDMzQwN0U0MEI0NDg2M0JBMDU1OThCNTI1NTZCMEFGNjk1NjJFNzZBMUE0NzM4NTQ=";


        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

         final Context context = getApplicationContext();
         connectWithHttpGet_IpAddress();

         etextUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_username);
         etextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_password);

         btnLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Login);
         btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!isOnline())
                {
                    showNoConnectionDialog(Login.this);
                }

                else
                {
                    connectWithHttpGet_LoginData();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void connectWithHttpGet_LoginData() 
    {

        class GetJSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONObject>
        {

             @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
             {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                    str_Device_IP_Address=sharedPref1.getString("ip_address", "a\n");
                    System.out.println("strCode  in Gsk_Demo ="+str_Device_IP_Address);

                    strUserName = etextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                    strPassWord = etextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                     pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);

                     pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                     pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                     pDialog.show();

                     System.out.println("Progress Dialog!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

             }

                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) 
              {
                     String strUrl = "http://test.xxxxxx.com/cms/json/w2iWS";
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                    Log.e("DoinBackground !!!!!","Method");
                    // Getting JSON from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(strUrl);
                    String jsonString=json.toString();
                    Log.e("jsonString in DoinBackground !!!!!","Method" + jsonString);
                    return json;
                }


              @Override
                 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)

                 {
                     pDialog.dismiss();

                     try
                     {
                            // Getting JSON Array
                            user = json.getJSONArray( KEY_REQUEST_ID );
                            JSONObject jsonObject = user.getJSONObject(0);

                            jsonObject.put(KEY_REQUEST_CODE, RequestCode);
                            jsonObject.put(KEY_CHANNEL_ID, stringChannelId);
                            jsonObject.put(KEY_IP_ADDRESS, str_Device_IP_Address);
                            jsonObject.put(KEY_USERNAME, strUserName);
                            jsonObject.put(KEY_PASSWORD, strPassWord);

                            String encrypted1 = EncodeDecodeAES.encrypt(jsonObject.toString(), textToEncrypt);
                            System.out.println("encrypted1  =" + encrypted1);

                            JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
                            inner.put(KEY_REQUEST, encrypted1);
                            inner.put(KEY_VENDOR_ID, "1");

                            String decrypted = EncodeDecodeAES.decrypt(jsonObject.toString(), encrypted);
                            System.out.println("decrypted  =" + decrypted);


                         } 

                     catch (JSONException e)

                     {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                     catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                 }

            }

        GetJSONParse getjsonparse = new GetJSONParse();
        getjsonparse.execute();

        }


    // Get Ip Address
        private void connectWithHttpGet_IpAddress() {

            class httpGetAsynchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    String url = "http://api.externalip.net/ip";

                    Log.e("!!STRING URL DATE DETAIL", "" + url);

                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                    Log.e("", "" + httpGet);

                    try {
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                        Log.e("HTTP.RESPONSE.DATE.DTAIL", "" + httpResponse);

                        System.out.println("HTTPRESPONSE");

                        InputStream inpustream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                                .getContent();

                        InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(
                                inpustream);

                        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(
                                inputstreamreader);

                        StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        Log.e("", "" + stringbuilder);

                        String strbuffer = null;

                        while ((strbuffer = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)

                        {
                            stringbuilder.append(strbuffer);
                        }

                        String strResponse = stringbuilder.toString();

                        /****************** Code For Shared Preferences **************************************/
                        sharedPref1 = getSharedPreferences(pref_filename, 0);
                        editor = sharedPref1.edit();
                        editor.putString("ip_address", strResponse);
                        Log.e("Returning value of doInBackground  REsponse:" ,strResponse);
                        System.out.println("IPADDRESS IN DOIN BACKGRAOUND");
                        editor.commit();
                        /***************** Code For Shared Preferences **************************************/
                    }

                    catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                        cpe.printStackTrace();

                        Log.e("Exception generates caz of httpResponse :", "-"
                                + cpe);
                    }

                    catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();

                        Log.e("Second exception generates caz of httpResponse :",
                                "-" + ioe);
                    }

                    return null;
                }

            }

            httpGetAsynchTask httpGetAsyncTask = new httpGetAsynchTask();
            httpGetAsyncTask.execute();
        }



    public static void showNoConnectionDialog(final Login login) 

    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(login);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.no_connection);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.no_connection_title);


        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.settings_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {

                login.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
            }
        });


        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_button_text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
            {
                return;
            }
        });


        builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                return;
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }



    public boolean isOnline()
    {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 

        {
            return true;
        } 

        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: webservice In java do you mean servlet or java web service..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Asynctask` is not invoked

```
JSONParse jp =new JSONParse();
jp.execute(params);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

`public final AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> execute (Params... params)`

Executes the task with the specified parameters.

You had no invoked asynctask before

```
 GetJSONParse get = new GetJSONParse();
 get.execute(params);
```

And you said i can't see the log message in `doInbackground`. i just ran your code and i can see the log

[image]

Comment: I have change my code line but still getting same status no any error no any exception even not any print the statement on the log cat.

Comment: @tazeenmulani post the updated code and do you see  `Log.e("DoinBackground !!!!!","Method")` in logcat??

Comment: yah prints the Log.e("DoinBackground !!!!!","Method") in logcat Before change my code line.

Comment: @tazeenmulani din't understand your comment. where do you call `.execute()` to invoke asynctask?

Comment: When i put this code "JSONParse jp =new JSONParse();
jp.execute(params);" it is not printing =Log.e("DoinBackground !!!!!","Method") in logcat.It was working before i put this code = JSONParse jp =new JSONParse();
jp.execute(params);

Comment: @tazeenmulani how it was working before coz i could not see any code that invoked the asynctask

Comment: My IpAddress code was working before i put your code line .I have post my updates code again .

Comment: @tazeenmulani how was asynctask `GetJSONParse` invoked before??

Comment: I'm saying connectWithHttpGet_IpAddress() method was working properly but right now not working and also not working this connectWithHttpGet_LoginData() method .I don't know where is the problem occurs.

Comment: @tazeenmulani that will not work. i wonder how. coz asynctask in not even invoked. You never called `.execute()`. see the docs the link my post. So i am wondering how was that possible

Comment: GetJSONParse not invoked.When i run Only progress bar is start.My both method id not working.Please help me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42580/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tazeenmulani)

Comment: I'm writing the code in connectWithHttpGet_LoginData()  " GetJSONParse getjsonparse = new GetJSONParse(); getjsonparse.execute();" and call this connectWithHttpGet_LoginData(); method in onCreate().

Comment: @tazeenmulani join the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42580/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tazeenmulani

Comment: @tazeenmulani does not work. but you must see the log in `doinbackground`. check the topic The4Steps in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html. Can you post the logcat and post the parse code also